# Route/url lookup from template? (Java Spark framework)

Tags: spark-java

Is there a way for [spark-java](http://sparkjava.com/) to do reverse url lookups of routes from the template?

Like Python Django, for example:

> Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name) matching a given view and optional parameters. Any special characters in the resulting path will be encoded using iri_to_uri().
>
> **This is a way to output links without violating the DRY principle by having to hard-code URLs in your templates:**

```
{% url 'some-url-name' v1 v2 %}
```

- [Built-in template tags and filters: url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

I have not seen an option in the Spark docs that talks about named routes … If this feature is not available (guessing not) how hard do you think it be to incorporate into the core framework? Where do we submit feature requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to estimate how hard it would be to add your wanted feature. I would suggest that you add it and then evaluate how long time it took.

Feature requests can be registered as issues at https://github.com/perwendel/spark

As Spark-java is open source and maintained by volunteers, it would probably be a better idea to submit a pull request where you have added the functionality you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to java but plan to add this feature as I get better at it. I'll look at how Django does it internally and maybe do some sort of port to Spark. With that said, thanks for taking the time to answer. I really wish there was some sort of listserv as I'd much rather prefer having conversations with other Spark users vs. have to worry about reputation on SO. :D